# Where are the files generated from a binary launched using launchd?

Tags: mac, cron, launchctl

I am trying to setup a cron job using `launchd`, seemed quite straight forward with `systemd` on linux, but on mac, even though I have the process running (it is a local server, and I can confirm the API is up and running) I cannot find the files generated by the running binary

This is the plist for my service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.RQEventLogger</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/navdeep/Desktop/RQEventLogger</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/navdeep/Desktop/RQEventLogger/bin</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    
  </dict>
</plist>
```

my code generates a json file that it serves and updates based on the API request so I have confirmed that the file was created.

I tried setting the working directory by setting `WorkingDirectory` key, but that didn't work.